# MVC 4 same logic with different view folders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and started with MVC 4. I want to make an online shop application.

-Same shopping logic will be used by two different web sites/domains.

-And the views must alter according to domain name and their mobile versions.

Logic file structe is like this:

```
Controllers/HomeController.cs
Controllers/ProductController.cs
Models/Home.cs
Models/Product.cs
```

View file structure for first domain:

```
Views/my_1st_Domain/Home/Index.cshtml
Views/my_1st_Domain/Home/Index.Mobile.cshtml
Views/my_1st_Domain/Home/Terms.cshtml
Views/my_1st_Domain/Home/Terms.Mobile.cshtml
Views/my_1st_Domain/Product/Index.cshtml
Views/my_1st_Domain/Product/Index.Mobile.cshtml
Views/my_1st_Domain/Product/Detail.cshtml
Views/my_1st_Domain/Product/Detail.Mobile.cshtml
```

View file structure for second domain:

```
Views/my_2nd_Domain/Home/Index.cshtml
Views/my_2nd_Domain/Home/Index.Mobile.cshtml
Views/my_2nd_Domain/Home/Terms.cshtml
Views/my_2nd_Domain/Home/Terms.Mobile.cshtml
Views/my_2nd_Domain/Product/Index.cshtml
Views/my_2nd_Domain/Product/Index.Mobile.cshtml
Views/my_2nd_Domain/Product/Detail.cshtml
Views/my_2nd_Domain/Product/Detail.Mobile.cshtml
```

The question is:
How do switch between domain specific view folders automatically?

It can be done manually by repeating this line everywhere:

```
return View("~/Views/" + getDomainSpecificFolder() + "/Home/Index" + getMobileSuffixIfNeeded() + ".cshtml");
```

Is there any easier way to change base view folder globally with one shot?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make own ViewEngine, and return specific view depending on your current domain.
In controller code you just need to return usual

```
return View();
```

And all logic will be handled in custom ViewEngine.

Here is some details about it -

- http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx
- http://www.headcrash.us/blog/2011/10/custom-view-engine-for-localized-views-with-asp-net-mvc-razor/

Basically you need to make `CustomViewEngine` class, that inherits [`RazorViewEngine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.razorviewengine%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and register it in `global.asax`. Then in that class you need to overwrite [`FindView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.virtualpathproviderviewengine.findview%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method, that will use path for view based your domain.